# Does "expire" have to be followed by "on"?

Tags: differences, australian-english

I found this on someone's resume:

> expires 12/10/2017

Is this correct or should it be

> expires **on** 12/10/2017

If it makes any difference, this resume is from someone in Australia.

Comment: On a different aspect, the main problem with that item is that the date is completely ambiguous.  As a Brit, I instantly read it as 12 October 2017; whereas an American would read it as December 10, 2017.  I suspect the Australians use the British format, but I'm not sure.  On the main Q. I agree with @MaxWilliams.

Comment: @TrevorD very good point. It seems the Australians follow the correct (troll) system : DMY. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Comment: What does your research show on the verb to "expire"? Have you tried to look up the dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"expires 12/10/2017"* is an acceptable **contraction** of *"expires on 12/10/2017"*